# React native not working with WSA (Windows subsystem for android)

Tags: android, windows, react-native, windows-subsystem-for-android

I'm trying to debug my React native application on WSA but it doesn't work saying that the port is already in use and the metro bundler doesn't connect, when trying to reverse the port (on actual device, it works without issues).

The warning which I get when running `yarn react-native run-android` is:

```
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb -s 127.0.0.1:58526 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

It installs the app but doesn't proceed:
[Error shown by app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MbmH.png)

And when I try to execute `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`, it ends up with this:

```
adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: Address already in use
```

As a result, the metro bundler doesn't work.